# Controller for classrooms and students

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, controller, rest

The actions I'm wondering about are `members`, `add_student`, and `remove_student`.  They work just fine, but they aren't RESTful and it *feels* like they should be handled (perhaps) by the `StudentsController`.

Note that `members` and `show` are the same. The only difference is that the `members.html.erb` view iterates over and displays `@classroom.students` while `show.html.erb` displays info about the classroom itself.

```
class ClassroomsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /classrooms
  def index
    @classrooms = Classroom.all.order('name ASC')
  end

  # GET /classrooms/1
  def show
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])

    authorize @classroom
  end

  # GET /classrooms/1/members
  def members
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])

    authorize @classroom
  end

  # GET /classrooms/new
  def new
    @classroom = Classroom.new
    @classroom.build_avatar

    authorize @classroom
  end

  # GET /classrooms/1/edit
  def edit
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
    @classroom.build_avatar unless @classroom.avatar

    authorize @classroom
  end

  # POST /classrooms
  def create
    @classroom = Classroom.new(classroom_params)

    authorize @classroom

    if @classroom.save
      redirect_to classrooms_path, notice: 'Classroom was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  # PUT /classrooms/1
  def update
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])

    authorize @classroom

    if @classroom.update(classroom_params)
      redirect_to edit_classroom_path(@classroom), notice: 'Classroom was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end

  def add_student
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
    @student = Student.find(params[:classroom][:student_ids][0])

    authorize @classroom

    @classroom.students << @student

    respond_to do |format|
      @count = @classroom.students.count
      format.js
    end
  end

  def remove_student
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
    @student = Student.find(params[:classroom][:student_ids][0])

    authorize @classroom

    @classroom.students.delete(@student)

    respond_to do |format|
      @count = @classroom.students.count
      format.js
    end
  end

  # DELETE /classrooms/1
  def destroy
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])

    authorize @classroom

    @classroom.destroy

    redirect_to classrooms_path
  end

  private

  def classroom_params
    params.require(:classroom).permit(:name, :description, avatar_attributes: [:id, :avatar, :_destroy],
      :student_ids => [])
  end

end
```

Here are the models:

```
# student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classroom_memberships, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :student
  has_many :classrooms, :through => :classroom_memberships
end

# classroom.rb
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classroom_memberships, :inverse_of => :classroom, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :munchkins, :through => :classroom_memberships
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The actions I'm wondering about are members, add_student, and remove_student. They work just fine, but they aren't RESTful [...]

True, they're not part the usual CRUD actions that can be expressed with HTTP verbs. But then neither are the default `new` or `edit` actions, so it's not like going beyond CRUD is automatically illegal.

Even so, associations do always present a bit of challenge. Are you adding the student to the class, or the class to the student?

However, in this case it appears that you already have a join model: `ClassroomMembership`. So going back to the CRUD actions, consider *what* you're creating when you call `add_student`: A membership.

So what you might want to do is simply make a `ClassroomMembershipsController`, since that's the resource you're manipulating. Said controller can then have the usual RESTful CRUD actions, keeping `StudentsController` or `ClassroomController` pretty clean.

This is just an idea, though. Again, if it's simpler to keep your actions on the `ClassroomController` then do that. But conceptually what you're doing is manipulating the association model.

Comment: Adding a `ClassroomMembershipsController` makes a lot of sense! Definitely a more RESTful approach. Follow-up question: `ClassroomMemberships` don't have their own views--so I guess I just render the `Classroom` view from the `ClassroomMembershipsController` and that's kosher?

Comment: @RobSobers Or you can just do a `redirect_to @membership.classroom`. A controller doesn't _need_ to have views; its purpose is merely to respond to requests, and sending a redirect is a response. The default `destroy` action doesn't have a view either, since it just redirects. Incidentally, I'd consider the name `Enrollment` for the join model, only because it sounds a little more straightforward. But renaming a resource is a chore and has knock-on effect, so don't do it lightly. It can be done of course, just know what you're getting yourself into :)

Comment: Good point. And I suppose in this case, I won't even need to redirect since both `add_student` and `remove_student` respond with JavaScript, which will be sent to whichever page is making the request.

Comment: @RobSobers Sure. In that case, I often find it easiest to respond with plain HTTP status codes, and no actual content. E.g. instead of `render ...` or `redirect_to ...`, you can just call `head :created` (when a membership was created), `head :conflict` if the membership already exists, etc. etc.. See [httpstatus.es](http://httpstatus.es/) for more. There are plenty of standardised response codes, that carry a lot of meaning

Answer (score 3):

You could refactor `add_student` and `remove_student` using blocks

```
  def add_student
    find_class_and_student do
      @classroom.students << @student      
    end
  end

  def remove_student
    find_class_and_student do
      @classroom.students.delete(@student)
    end
  end

  private

  def find_class_and_student
     @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
     @student = Student.find(params[:classroom][:student_ids][0])        
     authorize @classroom

     yield

     respond_to do |format|
        @count = @classroom.students.count
        format.js
     end   
  end
```

This is just pulling your code inside some other actions.